# Using only the def., how to show that for every cardinal there is a bigger one

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How Can I deduce from Cantor's Theorem that for every cardinal $\alpha$ there is a cardinal
$\beta> \alpha$.

A cardinal is an ordinal which is equal to its cardinality.

Comment: Which axioms of the set theory are you using? ZFC?

Comment: the axioms I am using ZFC

Comment: Then try the power set.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem

Comment: It doesnt help. It depends on what definition you use. Herre's my try: $\alpha$ is a cradinal so it's an ordinal, so it's a set, so $P(\alpha$) is a set. Now $|P(\alpha)|$ is a cardinal . Now how can I use Cantor's theorem to show that $|P(\alpha)| > \alpha$

Comment: How does Cantor's theorem "not help"?  If you use it, and the fact that $\mathcal{P}(\alpha)$ can be well-ordered, isn't it clear what to do?  What does your version of Cantor's theorem say?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Note that by Cantor's theorem there is no surjection from $\alpha$ onto $\mathcal P(\alpha)$. Let $\beta=|\mathcal P(\alpha)|$, then $\alpha<\beta$.